# vega-lite show all x-axis values

Tags: vega-lite

I have a vega-lite bar chart with years as the x-axis (counts as the y).  The user selects a range of years to show.  When the data is sparse, some years have a 0 count and are not showing on the chart.  How do I get all years in the range to show up?

Comment: You could set the number of ticks using the parameters `tickCount` or `values` for the axis. Please provide a [mre] for more detailed help.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by first setting my measure to be [computation] + 0.  This then caused everything to show.  Thus, I added a transform filter to the vega-lite to only include when the measure > 0.

```
"filter": "datum.countOf > 0"
```